# SimpleXMLElement uses wrong xsd namespace when xmlns is absent

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:fooBar xmlns:foo="foo.xsd" xmlns:bar="bar.xsd"><foo:element/><bar:element>value</bar:element></foo:fooBar>
```

However, my code sets the prefix/namespace for the second element (the one with value) to `foo`, even though I used `bar:element`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:fooBar xmlns:foo="foo.xsd" xmlns:bar="bar.xsd"><foo:element/><foo:element>value</foo:element></foo:fooBar>
```

Here's my code:

```
$base = "<foo:fooBar xmlns:foo=\"foo.xsd\" xmlns:bar=\"bar.xsd\"/>";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($base);
$foo = $xml->addChild("foo:element");
$bar = $xml->addChild("bar:element", "value");

echo($xml->asXML());
```

I've noticed that setting the third argument of `addChild` (the xmlns) to *anything* fixes the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:fooBar xmlns:foo="foo.xsd" xmlns:bar="bar.xsd"><foo:element/><bar:element xmlns:bar="arbitrary string">value</bar:element></foo:fooBar>
```

How can I have the second element use the correct prefix/namespace without using xmlns?

[Something like JSFiddle with my code](https://3v4l.org/VWvJe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the element `bar:element` using `addchild()` you need to pass as the third parameter the namespace - and this must match the original URI of the namespace you've already declared.  If you pass a different URI, then it will assume you want to declare a new namespace.  So using `"bar.xsd"` as the third parameter...

```
$base = "<foo:fooBar xmlns:foo=\"foo.xsd\" xmlns:bar=\"bar.xsd\"/>";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($base);
$foo = $xml->addChild("foo:element");
$bar = $xml->addChild("bar:element", "value", "bar.xsd");

echo($xml->asXML());
```

Will give...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:fooBar xmlns:foo="foo.xsd" xmlns:bar="bar.xsd">
    <foo:element/>
    <bar:element>value</bar:element>
</foo:fooBar>
```